# Encoding for movie genres in dataset

Tags: python, encoding, multilabel-classification

I have a movie dataset that contains a column that lists the movie's genre as such:

```
title    genres          
t1       ['Drama', 'Science Fiction', 'War']
t2       ['Action', 'Crime']
```

I want to encode them to be:

```
title  Drama  Science  Fiction  War  Action  Crime
t1     1      1                 1    0       0
t2     0      0                 0    1       1
```

I have tried MultiLabelBinarizer, but the output came out to be:

```
    ,   A   D   F   S   W   a   c   d   e   i   m   n   o   r   t   u   v
0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

How can I solve this problem? Is there another way for me to achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of `genres`?

Comment: @TomRon the datatype is object

Comment: @1ThunderousApplause I think what @TomRon means is, what are all the possible `genres` that you want be placed as a column?

Comment: @Ricardo I'm sorry, is that the unique values?

Comment: @1ThunderousApplause Yes.

Comment: @Ricardo sorry for the late reply, with df.unique(), it seems that the unique values are grouped per row, like: ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Science Fiction']", "['Action', 'Adventure', 'Comedy']", instead of each genre only being counted once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this is your df:

```
    title   genres
0   t1  [Drama, Science Fiction, War]
1   t2  [Action, Crime]
```

You should do something like this:

```
# edit
# consider adding this line if your df.genre is a string of list
df.genres = df.genres.apply(lambda x: eval(x))

exploded_df = df.explode(column='genres')
pd.get_dummies(exploded_df, columns=['genres']).groupby('title', as_index=False).sum()

# output
  title genres_Action   genres_Crime    genres_Drama    genres_Science Fiction  genres_War
0   t1  0               0               1               1                       1
1   t2  1               1               0               0                       0
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, but it came out as: genres_['Action', 'Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Science Fiction']. Is it perhaps a mistake in my data? The way the genre is formatted is exactly ['Genre1', 'Genre2'], does it affect the results?

Comment: I've updated the answer... It looks like your `genre` column is wrongly formatted as a string of list, like so: `"['Action', 'Adventure']"`

Comment: You are absolutely right. Reformatting the genres from "['Action', 'Adventure']" to ['Action', 'Adventure'] has solved the problem. Thank you so much!